# Globbing patterns for sub-projects in Grunt

Tags: build, glob, gruntjs

I have several sub-projects that I want to run against a single Gruntfile, as they all need the same tasks running against them. For example, I need to compile the Sass using Compass in each sub-project.

How is this possible using Grunt? I have tried globbing patterns:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: './bundles/*/public/styles',
    cssDir: './bundles/*/temp/styles'
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Running "compass" (compass) task
Errno::ENOENT on line 441 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/pathname.rb: No such file or directory - /Users/Oliver/Development/Personal/Reader/bundles/*
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Suggesting I cannot use globbing patterns in this way.

Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass/issues/15):

> Globbing patterns doesn't work there, since as you can see from the name it expects one directory. You can however create separate targets for each sub-project.